# Spring Integration: Publish/Subscribe: Is there a way for a subscriber to have messages queued for it even if it is temporary inactive?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, publish-subscribe

The scenario is as follows: I have a publisher that sends a message and a subscriber is down. How can I make sure that the subscriber still receives the message after it goes back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `QueueChannel` in between. This way the published message is going to be parked in the queue until you start a consumer for polling that queue.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-queuechannel

Comment: Thanks! Can you please share your opinion on this? An input QueueChannel, an output PublisherSubscriber channel, and a Bridge between them polling from the queue, and sending to the output channel. Once all are started, a message is being sent on the QueueChannel, which is ignored on the PublisherSubscriber end, because there are 0 registered subscribers. If a subscriber gets registered on the fly afterwards, while everything is still up, is there a way for the subscriber to see the message it has missed, because of not being subscribed at the time when the message was polled from the queue?

Comment: You probably need to take a look into the `durable subscription` in JMS: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/pagehelp/JMSjmssubscribersjmsudddurablesubscriberruntimetitle.html. And as Gary said in his answer use a JMS-backed channel. Kafka also has similar durable semantic with its `offset` feature. We don't have such an in-memory implementation in Spring Integration. And probably it does not make sense to have it since it is fully covered by messaging brokers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `QueueChannel` (in-memory) or one backed by a broker (RabbitMQ, Kafka, JMS, ...).